# Flot transparent bar graph with lines?

Tags: javascript, graph, flot

I've had great success getting flot to create line graphs, in part due to the quality of responses on this forum!

However either I'm trying to do something special, or can't figure out the search terms.  I'm trying to plot two datasets on the same graph:

Line graphs that represent temperatures
Bar graphs that represent when a device is active (it is either a 1 or a 0 value in the RRD). I want these as transparent background bars so I can see if the device is triggering properly and how long it is on for.

I have two problems;

- I can't get the device data to show as transparent graphs. Just line data
- I haven't tried merging the two datasets into a single graph yet. I'd like the device bar data to show as a full vertical bar, right now the y-axis is from 0 to 1.2, so there is a gap at the top of the graph. When I try and use a second axis, I get the numbers on the right hand side, but the the line graph doesn't show it's axis correctly.

Here is a snippet of the data that I'm working with:

```
"data" : [
     {
        "bars" : {
           "fillColor" : {
              "colors" : [
                 {
                    "opacity" : 1
                 },
                 {
                    "opacity" : 1
                 }
              ]
           },
           "lineWidth" : 0,
           "show" : "true"
        },
        "color" : "blue",
        "data" : [
           [
              "1421280000000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1421452800000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1421625600000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1421798400000",
              "1"
           ],
           [
              "1421971200000",
              "1"
           ],
           [
              "1422144000000",
              "1"
           ],
           [
              "1422316800000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1422489600000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1422662400000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1422835200000",
              "0"
           ]
        ]
    }
        "label" : "D1",
        "yaxes" : 1
     },
     {
        "bars" : {
           "fillColor" : {
              "colors" : [
                 {
                    "opacity" : 1
                 },
                 {
                    "opacity" : 1
                 }
              ]
           },
           "lineWidth" : 0,
           "show" : "true"
        },
        "color" : "red",
        "data" : [
           ]
              "1421280000000",
              "1"
           ],
           [
              "1421452800000",
              "1"
           ],
           [
              "1421625600000",
              "1"
           ],
           [
              "1421798400000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1421971200000",
              "1"
           ],
           [
              "1422144000000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1422316800000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1422489600000",
              "0"
           ],
           [
              "1422662400000",
              "1"
           ],
           [
              "1422835200000",
              "0"
           ]
        ],
        "label" : "D2",
        "yaxes" : 1
     }  
  ],
```

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows your problem?

Comment: OK, I've never created a fiddle before, and the graphing part is a component of a larger javascript file. However I've managed to extract it all into a separate file and got a fiddle working by taking an existing flot fiddle and cutting and pasting in code: https://jsfiddle.net/tb0skj9o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bars have the default width of 1 x axis unit and since your x values are so big this means that the bars have a width of 0 pixels. Add something like this to your `bars` options to make them wider and proceed from there:

```
"barWidth": 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 day in milliseconds
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a6811uf/) with the full example. You will see that some bars hide each other, to counter this look at the side-by-side or stacked-bars [plugins](http://www.flotcharts.org/plugins/) on the flot site.

Comment: Thanks again, I see the errors (bar width), I doubled them to make them contiguous. I also see that the lines part should not be in the global options. So using your fiddle, I've updated it and have only two other questions; Is there any way to hide the second y-axis (show:false doesn't seem to work), and any idea why there is a data gap for the last step on the left hand side?

Comment: Use `false` instead of `"false"` to hide the axis, not sure about the gap.